# What is the absolute configuration of carbon 5 in 5-bromo-2-methylhex-2-ene

Tags: stereochemistry

I am trying to work out the absolute configuration around carbon atom 5 in 5-bromo-2-methylhex-2-ene. Could someone please let me know if my working is correct? Does the wedged bond from C4 to C5 affect the structure of the molecule and its configuration?

[image]

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: you already answered your own question. small tip when determining absolute configuration: make sure the substituent with the lowest priority is facing AWAY from you (so it points into the piece of paper).

Comment: You are correct.